# How are the angle bending parameters defined in the MM2 force field?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, molecular-mechanics

I am currently looking through the openbabel implementation of the mm2 forcefield. While I understand most of the implementation, I don't get the definition of the angle bending parameters (see https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/blob/master/data/mm2.prm), which have the following form:

```
angle         1    1    1     0.450    109.470    109.510    109.500
angle         1    1    2     0.450    109.470    109.510    109.500
angle         1    1    3     0.450    107.800    109.900    110.000
angle         1    1    4     0.450    109.470    112.400    109.000
angle         1    1    5     0.360    109.390    109.410    110.000
angle         1    1    6     0.700    107.500    107.700    107.400
angle         1    1    8     0.570    109.470    108.800    109.500
angle         1    1    9     0.500    109.280    110.780    109.280
angle         1    1   11     0.650    109.500    107.500    109.500
angle         1    1   12     0.560    108.200    0.000      0.000
```

So they are of the form

```
<1.-atom-type> <2.atom-type> <3.atom-type> <force-constant> <1.angle> <2.angle> <3.angle>
```

However, I understand the angle bending to work like this:

[image]

There is an ideal bond angle $\theta _0$, and if the actual bond angle $\theta$ differs from $\theta _0$, this results in an increase in energy, e.g. of the form $\Delta E = (\theta _0 - \theta)^2$. Therefore, given an angle with three atom types a,b,c there should be only one angle $\theta _0^{a,b,c}$. So why are there three angles given for every combination?

Comment: After some digging around I found an explanation somewhere, though I am not sure if it is correct: The first angle seems to refer to $-XR_2-$, i.e. an atom with two additional alkyl chains, the second angle to $-XRH-$, i.e. an atom bonded to alkyl and H substituents and the third angle to $-XH_2-$.

Comment: And this of course makes sense, as hydrogen atoms are sterically less demanding, thus affecting the optimal angle.

Comment: We have decided against program specific tags.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Good to know for the future, but IMHO we should make an exception for openbabel ; )

Comment: @deusexmachina - there's an Open Babel forum outside of Chem.SE... :-)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Yeah, I know, now : ) Guess it is also of general interest for other MM2 implementations, though.